# customize wxTextCtrl autocomplete

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxTextCtrl object and set it to be autocomplete

```
wxArrayString _myStringArray;
_myStringArray.push_back("abc");
_myStringArray.push_back("alpha");
_myStringArray.push_back("bnm");

_myTextCtrl->AutoComplete(_myStringArray);
```

I type char 'a' into it. And then a popup shown with a list of related/suggested strings (i.e "abc" and "alpha"). Now I press 'down arrow key' in order to select a string. The first time I press the button the "abc" string is selected. The second time I press the button the "alpha" string is selected.

The problem is changing the string selection by pressing UP and DOWN arrow keys doesn't change the text control value. I want the text control value to be updated when the selected string changed by pressing UP and DOWN arrow key.

I thought I could do that manually if I know the event name. So the question is: what is the event name (or event macro) of changing string selection from a popup in a wxTextCtrl by pressing UP and DOWN arrow key?

Thanks

update: I am succeded on capturing KEY DOWN event by subclassing wxTextCtrl and then add an event handler for EVT_KEY_DOWN event.

```
void TextCtrlChild::keyHandler(wxKeyEvent& event)
{
   int _keyCode = event.GetKeyCode();
   if(_keyCode == 315 || _keyCode == 317){ //if UP or DOWN arrow key is pressed
     //TO DO: capture the highlighted string from the popup
   }
   event.Skip();
}
```

Now the question is how to capture the selected/highlighted string from the popup?

Comment: wx verfsion? os?

Comment: @igor I'm using wxGTK 3.0

Comment: did you install it from repository? build it yourself? is it using GTK+2 or GTK+3? Also, I believe the autocompletion was improved in TRUNK. You can try to compile the latest HEAD and see if it improves.

Answer (score 0):

The way autocompletion works is dictated by the system UI conventions, so it doesn't look like a good idea to interfere with it. If you really want to have immediate selection, consider using another control, such as `wxChoice`, instead.